# How do Dragoon and Daybreak pieces work in Team Battles?

Tags: super-smash-bros-ultimate

In normal matches, the Dragoon and Daybreak items in Smash Ultimate require a player to collect all three pieces before they can be used. How do these items work in team battles? If player A picks up the first two parts, then player B picks up the last part, which player gets to use the weapon if they are on the same team?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a team battle, the [Dragoon](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Dragoon) and [Daybreak](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Daybreak) will be granted to whoever collects the final piece amongst the team. They do not all need to be held by a single member (unless they are the only one on their team).

(The above is the case for both SSB4 and SSBU. In SSBB, a single team member must hold all the pieces.)